# How to change images in the Slider

Tags: wordpress

I translate site to WordPress (make a theme). I faced with such problem. 
I have this HTML code

```html
<div class="flexslider"><!-- .slider-->
<ul class="slides">
<li>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/slides/slide1.jpg" alt="" />
</li>
<li>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/slides/slide2.jpg" alt="" />
</li>
<li>
   <img  src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/slides/slide3.jpg" alt="" />
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This is the slider. There is a JS script, which is working with the slider. I need to make such action: user can fix images of the slider (by admin-bar) in the visual regime (without coding). For instance, to delete images, to change order of images, to load images, etc.
I guess that I need to use plug-in with opportunity of gallery or else. But I don't know anything about it :(
Help me, please, and sorry for my broken english

Answer (score 0):

Please try below plugin for flax slider in wordpress.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smart-flexslider/

If it not working for you then try it.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/flexslider